# Set label transparency in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, labeling

I have been trying to figure out how to set the transparency of my labels and label buffers in PyQGIS for an application I am building. I am using the "setCustomProperty" class from the QGIS API. I can't find anything in the API documentation that allows for setting transparency. This is possible in the QGIS GUI via a slider, but seemingly impossible in PyQGIS. Here is a snippet of my labeling code:

```
    self.mylayer.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
    self.mylayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/isExpression", True)
    self.mylayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", True)
    self.mylayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/bufferDraw", True)
    self.mylayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/bufferSize", "1")
    self.mylayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/bufferColor", "white")
    self.mylayer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Arial")
```

Shouldn't there be a custom property setting for transparency? Like a bufferAlpha or a textAlpha setting or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textTransp` has worked for me. You need to give it a value (string, integer, or float) between 0 and 100 (like a percentage):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", "true")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Arial")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "10")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "NAME")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/textTransp", "70")
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```